# Verifying login Visual_c#

Tags: c#

Good Day,

In Visual c#, I need a login screen to enter the main form, I created the login screen, with user-name and password. (user-name and password are fields in a stand-alone table in the database) How do I verify what the user types in the text-boxes to that in the database,

I'm a newbie to Visual c#
I could not find a good example on checking text against stored data to learn from...

plz help
Thanks

Comment: We need more precision : What is your DB ? How are stored the credentials ? In which tables ?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer precisely without knowledge about what database you are running.
However in any case you can use one of the built-in classes to connect to your database, depending on what database you are running. Then use a normal database query to verify the supplied credentials if they exist in the database.

You should read up on some database tutorials in C# for more info on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You should also avoid storing plain text password in your DB. A more secure aproach is to store some kind of hash value, usualy an MD5 hash of your password.

For validation you create the hash of the user entered password and compare that to the hash stored in your table.